# It is possible to use "log4j jms appender" to send messages to a QUEUE instead of a TOPIC (like I found in all the examples.)

Tags: java, log4j, jms

Like the title said, I want to send logs using "log4j.appender.jms" but to a queue. The configuration that I have is this:

```
log4j.appender.jms=org.apache.log4j.net.JMSAppender
log4j.appender.jms.InitialContextFactoryName=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
log4j.appender.jms.ProviderURL=tcp://localhost:61616
log4j.appender.jms.TopicBindingName=logTopic
log4j.appender.jms.TopicConnectionFactoryBindingName=ConnectionFactory
log4j.appender.jms.Threshold=ERROR
```

This configuration is working, but like you see, is sending the information to a Topic instead of a Queue.

So I want to know if someone knows if is possible to send this logs to a queue using an appender like this one? Any suggestions of how can I do this?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not using the base code.  See [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.java?revision=685796&view=markup), the log4j JMSAppender uses Topics not Queues.  You could always create a clone of this appender and switch all the Topics to Queues.

Comment: Thanks! for your Reply.. I was suspecting that.